# What could be a chemical cause for insomnia?

Tags: biology, medicine, chemistry

Would it be possible to realistically invent a substance that causes insomnia? What would be the uses and consequences of such a substance?

Comment: How does this fit into world building?

Comment: Anything can fit into world building :p

Comment: This question look simple enough to be answered by a short Google search. Unless you are looking for something specific.

Comment: A somewhat, high dose of methamphetamine should work well, I think. It's metabolized to amphetamine.

Answer (score 5):

Yes -  anything that inhibits melatonin. A more detailed explanation can be [found at this link](http://www.hypoglycemia.asn.au/2011/the-biochemistry-of-insomnia/)

> The major cause of insomnia is the failure of the body to produce sufficient amounts of the neurotransmitter melatonin. This chemical induces us to sleep in conditions of total darkness.

Thus, theoretically, if you could find something that inhibits the production of melatonin or causes serotonin deficiency, then that should cause insomnia.

Edit: There is a list of drugs that cause insomnia at the end of the link given, but they would have other side-effects and may cause insomnia due to other reasons.